# multi level approval workflow in powerapps with documents attached in the mail body

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

Requirement: User will download the template from gallery and edit it accordingly. Once it's done, user will fill the form and attach the document there only. (all the data is going to save in one of sharepoint list), on submit button, data will move to sharepoint list and email should trigger to requestor and up to two level approvers also (approvers are different based on different regions) with the document attached in all the emails.

how to implement this flow?

Comment: My suggestion is to firstly, have a go.  It's a low to no code environment and there is ample documentation online to help you achieve what you need.  Break it down into smaller chunks and just start, seriously, it's what you should do.  SO is not a place for free consulting, you really need to come here with an issue that needs to be solved, right now, you have a solution that needs to be built, that's a different thing.

Comment: issue is that email are not triggering with attachments to both the requestor and approver when I use start an approval workflow template.

Comment: Then you should update your question with all of the details relevant to the issue which helps others work out what might be going wrong.  Provide as much detail as you can.  That includes screenshots, JSON definitions, expressions, etc.  Just make sure you obfuscate and blur any sensitive information.